# Apex Code - Region for as C#

Tags: apex, c#, vs-code

I just want to know, if there is any practice like C# #Region in Apex code?

I would like to be able to reduce some parts of my code in Visual Studio Code.

Is there any way to do it?

For anyone who wonders, which kind of witchcraft I'm talking about, here an example:

[image: Region example in C#]

Thank you for your answer.

Edit :

Sorry, i though the screen was enough.
The objective is to as @david reed said : folding my code in a class so i would be able to fold for exemple theses parts :

[image]

Comment: For non-C# programmers, could you please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish in Apex? Are you asking about code folding?

Comment: It would help if you would explain _what a C# "Region" is_. Your screenshot doesn't really tell people what it is if they don't already know about it.

Comment: I've edited my post, tell me if you need more information and sorry for my bad explaination !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`#region`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region) and `#endregion` define a code folding unit.

The Apex extensions for Visual Studio Code added support for these directives [in 2018](https://github.com/ntotten/salesforcedx-vscode/commit/2229f0e635a831dd4a29d2c7a5ec53b932fb3b24). The directives *must* be located in comments; `#region` directives aren't understood by the Apex compiler but by the Visual Studio Code editor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i wanted to have !

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on David's answer with an example. In VSCode, you start the folding region with `//#region` and end it with `//#endregion`.

```
public static void createAccounts(Integer amount) {

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    //#region Start

    for (Integer i=1;i<=amount;i++) {
        accounts.add(
            new Account(
                Name='Name ' + i
                )
            );
    }

    //#endregion

    insert accounts;

}
```

[image]